# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**I have an issue with quit function, the button should back to the index page:**

```
<button id="quit-button" onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Quit</button>
```

**and the function is:**

```
 handelQuitButtonClick = () => {
    this.playButtonSound();
    
    if (window.confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Exit The Quiz?')) {
        this.props.history.push('/');
    }
  };

handleButtonClick = (e) => {
    switch (e.target.id) {
      case "quit-button":
        this.handelQuitButtonClick();
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  };
```

It is showing this message in the console

```
play.js:124 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
    at Play.handelQuitButtonClick (play.js:124:1)
    at Play.handleButtonClick (play.js:139:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299:1)
```

anyone can help?

Comment: Actually, from what I can see of the code in your repo you linked in a comment below, this `Play` component is rendered by a `Route` component and should be passed the route props, i.e. it should have a defined `history` prop injected and available. You are using `react-router-dom` v5, so the router, `Switch`, `Route` components all seem fine. Did you ensure you've *actually* installed all of your dependencies before running the project? From the project root run `npm install` then `npm start`.

Comment: Problem solved yesterday

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrapp your component with the hook withRouter

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

When export your class you add it exemple if your class called Play

```
export default withRouter(Play );
```

Comment: it's showing an error you can see the full code here: https://github.com/nawarmohra/Quiz-app/blob/main/src/components/quiz/play.js

Comment: @nartyam I edited the answer you use react-router-dom 6 we need to import it from it

Comment: could you please explain to me how because the solution up didn't work!

Comment: You add this on line 9 import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

And replace line 304 by this export default withRouter(Play );

Comment: I did this solution and get this error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12MU53WsMy5vr3-A_8XcYXnDu0RN0CPdJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @nartyam I don't know if there is a way to have a chat with screen share in the stack overflow

Comment: Sorry am at work now i don't have access to my gmail from this laptop,

Comment: But i found the solution in your package.json you used the react-router-dom v6 and the withRouter hoc is deprecated from this version so you need to downgrade your react-router-dom version and call npm install or yarn install